# loadeFileAsString in jar file don't works

Tags: java, file, jar, export

This is my code to read a map and print it on my screen :

```
private void loadWorld(String path){
    String file = Utils.loadeFileAsString(path);
    String[] tokens = file.split("\\s+");
    width = Utils.parseInt(tokens[0]);
    height = Utils.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    spawnX = Utils.parseInt(tokens[3]);
    spawnY = Utils.parseInt(tokens[4]);

    tiles = new int[width][height];
    for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
        for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
            tiles[x][y] = Utils.parseInt(tokens[(x+y*width)+4]);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working in my Eclipse's project, but when i'm exporting this as an executable file, it's told me he can't find .\res\worlds\worlds1.txt

An idea ?

EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is the error's image :

[image: Error message]

Comment: I think you are using relative path which is not recognizable in your code?       **can you post up your stack trace?**

Comment: I'm new to this network, can you explain me what's my stack trace please ?

Comment: My idea is that file `.\res\map\map1.txt` is not found. Please define what is expected result. Please show what is a `path` value. Maybe `path` = `./res/map/map1.txt` will work?

Comment: @Antoine please google it

Comment: I edited the post, will it help you ? I'm realy sorry Kick Buttowski, but i don"t understand you :/